# Can't I add customHeaders via web.config to support CORS for WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, cors

This link: 
"http ://new%20behavior%20and%20include%20it%20in%20the%20enpoint%20configuration"

says:

"**You have to new behavior and include it in the endpoint configuration**"

Isn't it enough to add customHeaders in the web.config to enable CORS for a WCF Service like:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type, x-requested-with, Accept />
...
```

If not enough, why?

Comment: Which link is that? Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether those values are enough or not to enable CORS for WCF will depend on which client you're using, and which endpoint you're accessing, and whether the service is capable of handling the preflight (OPTIONS) request which the CORS-based client will send to the resource. If the only headers your clients send are the ones you list, and your service can handle the OPTIONS request, then that should be fine. If you need to send additional headers (i.e., if you want to access a `BasicHttpBinding`-based endpoint, you'll also need the `SOAPAction` header), then it's not.

Also, since this uses an IIS feature, this will not work for self-hosted services. And this is enabling CORS from all domains, which may be what you need but you should be aware of that.